# R: Arranging axis using ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I am trying to present my data using ggplot2. My dataframe is build up like this:

```
    type     count
1   exon      4
2   intron    3
3   intron    1
4   exon      10
..  ...      ..
```

I am trying to present the data by plotting as histograms and boxplots, but I encounter some problems.
For the histograms I used the following code:

```
ggplot(hisdat, aes(x=count, fill=type)) + 
    geom_histogram(binwidth=.5, position="dodge")
```

and that gives me this plot:

[image: Histograms]

As you can see the counts in the bottom of the plot are arranged such that 10 follows 1 and 100 follows 10. I arrange them from the first single number of the number count. How do I get it to go from 1-148?

For the boxplot I have the same trouble and on top of that my plot is not looking like a boxplot at all. Is my code wrong?

```
ggplot(hisdat, aes(x=type, y=count, fill=type)) + geom_boxplot()
```

It gives me this result:

[image: Boxplot]

Comment: Your variable `count` doesn't seem to be numeric. Try `hisdat$count <- as.numeric(as.character(hisdat$count))`

Comment: Arh! All this time i thought it was something much more complex. Thank you for clearing this up!

Answer (score 1):

since the other part of your question has already been answered in the comments here is the answer to this part:

> How do I get it to go from 1-148?

```
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text=
                     "    type     count
1   exon      4
2   intron    3
3   intron    1
4   exon      10")

library(ggplot2)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = reorder(type, count), y = count, fill = type)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")
```

Comment: I tried to apply it to a dataframe with much more diversity in the numbers (from 0 to 2,294,744), but still with 36976 variables. Is this dataframe too big to use with ggplot()? It seems like my systems time out when I try it.